# NHibernate vs Entity Framework 6 performance for big number of users

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building big web application that should communicate with the database very often. 
I'm wondering what library should I use for communication NHibernate or Entity Framework 6?

Here is my application specs:

- **Users:** The application built for big number of users, lets start with 100,000 users registered. 50,000 users online, every user can send up to 1 message at second. **15,000 messages got sent every second**.
- **Memory:** It's very important to keep memory in normal state so I suppose that I should use `LazyLoad`?
- **The database:** The database structure is very complicated.
- **Users engine:** Currently I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity with Entity Framework 6 `UserStore`.

Important things:

- **The comfort is very important to me!**
- **Code First:** I hate when code gets generated.
- **Performance:** The performance is the most important thing here!

Comment: Actually you should use NHibernate instead of Fluent NHibernate . Fluent NHibernate is a tool that let you build nhibernates mapping xml files on the fly.

Comment: @Beatles1692 I updated my post, the question is still the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As someone who is using NHibernate for several years I might not be the right person to help you choose between EF or NHibernate but here are some general pieces of advice that I've learned these years:

-**Be in control** : I mean choose an ORM that let you control every aspect of its functionality.Fortunately for us , NHibernate is one of them. You can call SPs and other Database objects and map their result to your objects.You can write interceptors to intercept NHibernate functionality and so on.

-**Avoid general ORM issues from the start**:one of them (which has a big impact on performance) is [SELECT N+1](http://ayende.com/blog/1328/combating-the-select-n-1-problem-in-nhibernate).

-**Use specific profiler to see how your ORM is working**: I think this is really important for us to be able to see how the ORM is working and what queries are actually running in the back.

-**Use cache whenever possible**: I don't know about EF but Nhibernate has a second level cache mechanism that you can use to cache ferequently read and static data in memory to gain a better performance

-**Have a plan for load testing and stress testing your application**: No matter which ORM you choose , there will be times that you should increase the performance of your application.I think the best way to see how an application is working on a large scale is to somehow simulate it and try to tweak it so that it works in its best condition.

-**Have a Plan B** : ORMs are designed to help us to solve the dilemma of storing data in tables and using them as objects in our application.Thus they are doing something extra for us and they tend to be slower than using data in tabular format.So there are times that it would be better to use a plain tabular format in our application instead of converting it to objects (Take showing a list of information for instance)

P.S. This might be off topic but have you consider using a NoSql database instead of a relational one ?

Comment: I am also using `NHibernate` for long time and I want to know what better, `NHibernate` or `EF6` by performance because I know that `NHibernate` is very comfortable and gives me full control.

P.S What is non-sql database?

Comment: Sorry my mistake it's actually NoSql(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database.

Comment: If you are familiar with NHibernate then I suggest you take a look at this :http://www.dennisdoomen.net/2013/03/entity-framework-56-vs-nhibernate-3.html

Comment: Currently no, maybe in future.

Comment: I read this article already but there are no comparison between `NHibernate` performances and `EF6` performances.

Comment: Here's a list of comparison by Ayende : http://ayende.com/blog/4351/nhibernate-vs-entity-framework-4-0

Comment: @Beatles1962 This article is about `NHibernate 2` and `EF4`. I need `NHibernate 3.3 or newer` and `EF6`.

Comment: I know but as you may have noticed he's talking about features of NH 2.0 so NH 3.3 already has them and we should see if there's an equivalent feature implemented in EF 6 for each of them (Batch writing ,Second Level Cache and so on)

Comment: I found this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2013/12/09/fetch-performance-of-various-net-orm-data-access-frameworks.aspx . Here they talking about `EF6` and `NHibernate 3.3.3.4`. As you can see `EF6` without cache tracking are much faster the `NHibernate 3.3.3`.

Comment: I can't believe the results that is mentioned in this article :) but I do agree with the author when he says "Having high performance means you have to engineer for that too. It doesn't come out of the box" .I don't use dotTrace to see if NHibernate is slow but I use NHProf(www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof‎).I think may be we can ask Ayende to take a look at these tests and says what he thinks .

Comment: I did some tests by myself and look, `EF6` is way slower than `NH 3.3.3.4`!!

Comment: Have you seen this one (http://ormeter.net/) ?

Comment: Turning off a very important function in an orm (entity tracking) will of course make everything faster, there's no need to check for existing entities in the first level cache, no need to keep track of them to persist changes automatically, etc. Then you're back into a glorified IDbConnection wrapper where you have to code things yourself.

Comment: BTW you can use NH in not tracking mode also.It has stateless sessions that don't track changes of objects.In a load test I compared stateless sessions of NH and dapper.net and NH was as fast as dapper.net